# On device reboot alarm is not going off at specific time

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am novice to android. I am developing alarm application in android. I have done following code which will work when device is on but on device reboot it will not work for me. I stored that alarm in shared preferences and retrieved from it. When device reboot I reschedule alarm from **OnBootReceiver** . I have already mentioned permissions to Android-manifest.For testing purpose I have taking hard-coded values. Please check following code and help me I researching on it from one and half day. Anyone has idea. Thanks.

**public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener**{

```
  int mHour = 14;
  int mMinute = 48;
  static String prefkey="SHARED_KEY";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   SharedPreferences preferences  =getSharedPreferences(prefkey,Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("min",mMinute);
        editor.putInt("hour",mHour);
        editor.commit();
   }
}
```

**public class OnBootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver** {

```
    int sethour,setmin;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "booting....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SharedPreferences preferences=context.getSharedPreferences(FirstActivity.prefkey,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sethour=preferences.getInt("hour",14);
    setmin=preferences.getInt("min",48);
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,setmin);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,sethour);
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND,0);


    AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i=new Intent(context,RepeatingAlarm.class);

    PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,sender1);

}
```

}

**public class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver** {

```
   static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer ;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Trigger the alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
   mMediaPlayer.create(getcontext,R.raw.warm).start();
   }
```

}

In **AndroidManifest.xml-->**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
 <receiver android:name="com.vidushi.alarmsystem.RepeatingAlarm"></receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".OnBootReciever" android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
```

Comment: Have you added the permission in menifest file </application> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: Thanks for reply.Yes I have already done that, sorry I forget to mention it and on device reboot Toast MSG Booting... is also coming.

Comment: Does code work without boot receiver? E.g. set alarm on button click.

Comment: It means that your code which sets the alarm is not working and it is not related to Boot completion

Comment: @Nikita: Yes It works on button click fine.

Comment: @PavanMore can you extract all code related to setting alarm to separate function. And call this function from `onClick` and `onReceive` so you can be sure they execute the same code?

Comment: @Maneesh: Yes, you are right. I think problem in broadcasted intent that will not catchhed by RepeatingAlarm receiver.

Comment: @Nikita If I call method from receiver then it force closes the application on booting.

Comment: It gives me NULL pointer excetion on SharedPreferences preferences=getcontext.getSharedPreferences(FirstActivity.prefkey,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  line.

Comment: @Nikita : I removed that exception that comes due to some of mistakes. But main problem is not solved that alarm not goes off after reset. I also check shared values in receiver which I set in firstActivity, that also coming true after device reboot. I think pending intent is not fired in this case.

Answer (score 1):

May be when android calls your OnBootReceiver class, it passes it's own context, not context from your application. So it can't find shared preferences because android doesn't have them. Try to use your own context instead of one you get in `onReceive` method. You can create `Application` class with `context` like this and initialize it on application start:

import android.content.Context;

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        context=getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

}
```

You also need to add following attribute to  tag in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:name=".Application"
```

[Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm)

And then use `Application` to get shared preferences:

```
Context context = Application.getContext();
SharedPreferences preferences=context.getSharedPreferences(FirstActivity.prefkey,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I already manage to get context now I am facing problem alarm not goes off after rebooting I think problem in pending intent please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app installed on the sd card? If it is, it wont receive 'boot completed' notifications.

See [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)